# Reset Azure ADB2C user password from central location

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a unique requirement for a password reset.

We have users without email(or have invalid email), they just signup using a username.

So, to reset passwords, we want to have a separate UI application for support people that will allow resetting users' passwords without needing to send the password over email or can be sent to the common support email of the organization.

Is there a way we can use Graph API for this purpose? Custom policies need email to send passwords over(don't want the user's phone numbers at this moment).

Appreciate any leads in this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you [can](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/changing-the-password-programmatically-in-azure-ad-b2c-3fbbd9fa82c6).

But not ideal. The support person knows the password. And how does the user get informed of the password?

The correct way is to use a [magic link](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-magic-link) that contains the username and when the user clicks on the link, they get the reset password flow. That way only the user knows the password.

Comment: Thanks, @rbrayb. I am going to try the first option. To communicate passwords, they use a separate messenger which works on organization Windows AD. Doesn't need an email. The organization is small and most of the employees are temporary so no emails created(just to save some $$).

Comment: Hi @rbrayb: I tries above solution but I am getting below error:

{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
        }
    }
}